# How to add clickable link to Foundation tooltip

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation, frontend

I currently have a header tag that I've attached Foundation's tooltip to per the [documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/tooltips.html). I want the tooltip itself to be clickable so I can show a modal on click, but it won't work because every time I hover away from the div the tooltip is attached to, the tooltip disappears.

I've tried manipulating the element with .hide() and .show() from jQuery, with no success. How can I force the tooltip to hide and stay when I want it to? Thanks!

```
<h5 data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" title="<a>Click here</a>">Hover for tooltip</h5>
```

Comment: Can you provide a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? I think I might have a solution but I want to test it on jsfiddle before posting it

Comment: @GilleQ. Very easy to create your own if you want to test a solution ► https://jsfiddle.net/q9doz17d/

Comment: found a solution on jsfiddle :D
see answer below

Comment: @Jay I answered in the same time, but in a different way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q9doz17d/3/) working for what you need:

I added the attribute: `data-allow-html="true"` and `data-disable-hover="true"` and then I handle the pop up show and hide by myself like this:

```
$("body").on("mouseenter", ".has-tip", function() {
    $(this).foundation("show");
});

$("body").on("mouseleave", ".tooltip", function() {
    $(this).siblings(".has-tip").first().foundation("hide");
});
```

It is the most generic example but you can now know where to start

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution (http://jsfiddle.net/abbylangner/XHb4Z/)
Basically, where you would call the .tooltip() method on target, you can add the options as JSON.

```
    function setClickableTooltip(target, content){
    $( target ).tooltip({
        show: null, // show immediately 
        position: { my: "right top", at: "left top" },
        content: content, //from params
        hide: { effect: "" }, //fadeOut
        close: function(event, ui){
            ui.tooltip.hover(
                function () {
                    $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(400, 1); 
                },
                function () {
                    $(this).fadeOut("400", function(){
                        $(this).remove(); 
                    })
                }
            );
        }  
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    setClickableTooltip('#t1', "some basic content");
    setClickableTooltip(
        '#t2',
        'diff content with <a href="http://abbysdoor.com">link</a> :)'
    );
});
```

credit to Abby Langer